# I think this is another React/JS context issue, how do I extract this variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array[] of tracks that I receive from an API.
I pass it to a map function which will return a track for every track in tracks. I want to export a variable (Song) specific to that track to be be processed in my event handler as such. The only thing thats not working is the scope of song. I cant set the state of song in my map function or the component goes into an infinite rerender loop.

```
handleEnter(){
   //I want to get the song into this context and play it here
    this.props.mouseEnter();
}

handleLeave(){
    //same for pausing
    this.props.mouseLeave();
}

createTrack(track){
    var song = new Audio([track.preview_url]);
    return   ( 
        <div className="image" key={track.id}>
            <img
                className="img-circle"
                src={track.album.images[0].url}
                onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this)}
                onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
            />
            <p className="showMe"><span>{track.name}</span></p>
        </div>
    );
}

getTracks(){
    if(this.props.tracks) {
        console.log(this.props.tracks);
        return (
            <div>{this.props.tracks.map(track => this.createTrack(track))}</div>
        );
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchMessage();
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>{this.getTracks()}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use .bind, you can send it to `handleEnter` and `handleLeave`.

```
handleEnter( trackID ) {
    // trackID available here
}

createTrack(track){
    var song = new Audio([track.preview_url]);
    return   ( 
        <div className="image" key={track.id}>
            <img
                className="img-circle"
                src={track.album.images[0].url}
                onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind( this, track.id )}
                onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind( this, track.id )}
            />
            <p className="showMe"><span>{track.name}</span></p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

It's typically [best practice](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) to not use .bind in react since it creates a new function on every render. Rather, you should create a `<Track />` component, pass it the track, then pass `handleEnter` and `handleLeave` as props.

```
const track = ( props ) => {

    let { track, handleEnter, handleLeave } = props;

    const onMouseEnter = () {
        handleEnter( track.id );
    }

    const onMouseLeave = () {
        handleLeave( track.id );
    }

    return (
        <div className="image" key={track.id}>
            <img
                className="img-circle"
                src={track.album.images[0].url}
                onMouseEnter={ onMouseEnter }
                onMouseLeave={ onMouseLeave }
            />
            <p className="showMe">
                <span>{track.name}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    );

};
```

then in your render, you'd map like you're doing and output `<Track />` [pure components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) instead of full-on components

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

```
handleEnter(track, e){
    // you will get the full track object and use the data 
    this.props.mouseEnter();
}

handleLeave(track, e){
    // you will get the full track object and use the data 
    this.props.mouseLeave();
}


componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchMessage();
}

render(){
    const createTrack = (track, index) => {
      var song = new Audio([track.preview_url]);
      return   ( 
        <div className="image" key={'track-'+ index}>
            <img
                className="img-circle"
                src={track.album.images[0].url}
                onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this, track)}
                onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind(this,track)}
            />
            <p className="showMe"><span>{track.name}</span></p>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return(
        <div>{this.props.tracks ? this.props.tracks.map(createTrack) : null }</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between what you wrote and what I wrote? Like you define createTrack as an annonymous function under render() while I defined it as a class function